# CRUD in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, crud

Could you please give me a piece of advice about how to implement CRUD or DB(PouchDB) modifications using FORMs or any other efficient way in Electron?

The point is I would like whole application to behave as desktop tool and it seems to be possible in Electron. However I cannot determine the best way to do this especially if I would like to add to nice eye-candy tricks to make UX as smooth as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all electron is not responsible for the visual appearance of your application. It is a framework which wraps your webapp into a desktop application.

That means you need to use standard web technologies (html/js/css) to create your site including 'eye-candy' and animations.

My suggestion is to do a tutorial which explains how to connect electron with a javascript framework like angular. If this is running you can attach a database and all the hot shizzle afterwards.
This tutorial is very good and well explained:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-desktop-applications-with-angularjs-and-github-electron

enjoy!